# Github pages hosted jekyll blog post loop not showing but pages are working

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I created a jekyll blog on my computer and it's working pretty fine on localhost:4000. and then I created a github pages repo like username.github.io. then I uploaded my local jekyll site using github windows client. after all file syncked I reloaded my github page URL. then my jekyll blog popup. but there is a problem. that is my posts are not showing on front page. but other blog parts are showing and working. eg: pages are working. I didn't do any modification to any file on my blog.

here is my github repo screenshot: 
[here is my github repo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziNu7.png)

here is my github page look:
[my github page look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twR0x.png)

Comment: An image worth nothing to debug. Gibe you repository url, it will be easiest to spot your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you publish a blog post dated 2016-02-12 17:21:45 **-0800** it will be in the **future** until 2016-02-13 01:21:45 **GMT**. So github page and jekyll will not publish it except if you set `future:true` in your `_config.yml`.

Comment: I edited _config.yml with future:true and edited sample blog post located in _post directory to past day in url and in the post but still not working.